# How to generate html report in local workspace from sonar-scanner from command line

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

Hi do I generate HTML reports in local workspace. I have following  properties in sonar-scanner report file

but couldn't see any html report

```
 sonar.issuesReport.html.enable=true
 sonar.issuesReport.json.enable=true
 sonar.report.export.path=sonar-report.json
 sonar.issuesReport.console.enable=true
```

how do I generate HTML report from command line.

Comment: You should provide more information, such as SonarQube version number and plugins used. Chances are that you use a [deprecated](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Report+Plugin) feature.

Answer (score 0):

sonar-scanner doesn't support the generation of the report during analysis. You should use SonarQube server to see results of the analysis.